# Dart Timer works in Android but not working on iOS

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a timer on dart to make the obscure text visible for half a second. It is working properly on Android Simulator but not working on iOS. What would be the issue? Any suggestions? VS Code is not showing any errors.

```
import 'dart:async';

class MyTextField extends StatefulWidget {
// ...


        onChanged: (value) {
          if (widget.obscureText) {
            setState(
              () {
                obscureText = false;
              },
            );
            Timer(
              const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
              () {
                setState(
                  () {
                    obscureText = true;
                  },
                );
              },
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```